How can I transfer ownership of a YouTube channel from an organization account to my personal accout?
I have a Google Workspace for Business subscription that is no longer needed. I'd like to shut it down to save the monthly cost.
There is however a YouTube channel linked to it and I'd like to transfer the channel to my free personal Google account before terminating the subscription.
Can this be done?

Asking because I was courageous enogh to try but 2FA "click on such and such device" didn't work and I had a chance to fact-check and verify before pulling the trigger.

In order to change ownership of a YouTube channel it must be part of a brand account.

Change channel owners & managers with a Brand Account
First, check if your channel is connected to a Brand Account. If it's
not, you can change channel managers, but not owners. To transfer
channel ownership, convert to a Brand Account by removing all roles in
the permissions set up.

